# Jetty: How to redirect base url programmatically?

Tags: redirect, jetty

I have to redirect    **myURL/** to **myURL/webApp/**

I found this piece of code

```
Server server = new Server();
RewriteHandler rewrite = new RewriteHandler();

RedirectPatternRule redirect = new RedirectPatternRule();
redirect.setPattern("/");
redirect.setReplacement("/myWebApp/");  // Getting compile error cannot resolve setReplacement method
rewrite.addRule(redirect);
```

Also, I didn't find setReplacement() in jetty documentaion.

https://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/8.0.0.M1/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/rewrite/handler/RedirectPatternRule.html

How can I achieve this redirect to base URL?

Comment: What version of Jetty? (Jetty 8.x is EOL / End of Life)

Comment: using jetty 9.4.14 v20181114